# Using dummy modules to replace optional modules during Fortran compilation

Tags: module, fortran

I'm trying to develop an interface to a large Fortran package, which we wish to use from our in-house software (also Fortran). However, this interface is entirely optional and the original software package should be able to compile on its own. As a result, I've created dummy modules to provide interfaces for all the `use <module name>` statements in our code when we compile without the optional package.

Is this the best way to do things? At the moment, to resolve all the dependencies, I'm essentially just copying the entire large package's modules into a dummy directory and leaving only type declarations. Is there a better way to do things?

Comment: This is how I do it in my code. The build system then chooses, if the real version or the dummy one should be built.

Comment: Do I understand it right, that your dummy modules are empty? Then I would suggest using conditional compilation with `#ifdef ... #endif` and defining appropriate symbols.